# Ruby on Rails graphing gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graph, rubygems

What Ruby on Rails gems are available to graph data?

This should include the ability to create pie charts, bar graphs, etc.

Please include a link to the gem, its support docs, or a screenshot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at http://www.highcharts.com/. As it's frontend stuff, a gem is not needed to integrate it.