# Creating a graph off of values of model variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I was wondering if there was some way to create a graph off the values of a particular attribute of a model. The X axis would just be the created_at date and the Y axis would be the numerical value of that model. I can't seem to find any kind of gem to help me with this as gems seem to want the numerical value to be a count.

Thanks!

Comment: Try [gruff](https://github.com/topfunky/gruff)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141742/ruby-on-rails-graphing-gems

Answer (score 0):

serve these data as json and use javascript to do it is much easier.

You might want to look into D3 library.

https://d3js.org/

or contour (also built upon D3)

https://forio.com/contour/get_contour.html